# Integral Problem : Remaining x value after stating solution in terms of du

Tags: integration

I was doing this problem and was having some problems understanding what I should, as there seems to be an x value still remaining.

$\int{\sqrt{1\ + \ (\frac{\sqrt{35x}}{7})^2}} dx$

Used integration by substitution method:

I made  $u = \frac{\sqrt{35x}}{7} $, which inturn resulted in $du = \frac{35}{14\sqrt{35x}} dx$

$\int{\sqrt{1\ + \ (u)^2}} \frac{14\sqrt{35x}}{35}du$

And this is where I am stuck, I seem to still have an x value.

I know that simplifying the problem ahead of time, would resolve the complexity of the problem, but I wanted to see whether I could still get a solution if I did not simplify.

Comment: Can you express $\sqrt {x} $ in terms of $u $? (You never said what your $u$ is.)

Comment: Try $u=1+\left(\sqrt{35x}/7\right)^2$. In general, try to add any "nearby" constants to your choice of $u$.

Comment: @Ian I have updated my answer to reflect what u is.

Comment: Your choice of $u$ means that a multiple of $\sqrt{x}$ is a (different) multiple of $u$. So you have $C \int \sqrt{1+u^2} u du$ for some (explicit) constant $C$. In general when doing say $\int f_1(x) f_2(x) dx$ by substitution, you may be able to write $f_1(x) dx$ as $f_3(u) du$, but then you still need to be able to represent $f_2(x)$ as some $f_4(u)$, which may require some additional algebra (based on your original definition of $u$).

Comment: For example, $\int x \sqrt{x+1} dx = \int x \sqrt{u} du$ where $u=x+1$, but then $x=u-1$ so you really have $\int (u-1) \sqrt{u} du$. That intermediate step where you wrote an integral with both $x$ and $u$ should be regarded as scratch work, not a proper step (but it is useful scratch work).

Comment: @team-erdos While it works out that way, I'd prefer this way in this particular case, because it makes "dx" be a multiple of "u du". Without doing that it takes a little bit more work to express dx in terms of u.